# The statement "$\alpha$ is a cardinal" is not absolute

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Jech in his "Set Theory" states without elaboration that cardinal concepts are not absolute generally. I think this is problematic. Any thought?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider a countable elementary submodel of $V_\kappa$ for some cardinal $\kappa>\omega_1$.

Since $\omega_1$ is definable there, it is in the submodel. Great, now take a transitive collapse. That is a countable transitive model of some amount of set theory. But now $\omega_1$ was collapsed to a countable ordinal.

So we have a countable ordinal and a transitive set which thinks this ordinal is an uncountable cardinal. So being a cardinal is not absolute.

Comment: Now I believe that cardinal is absolute, but there are somethings wrong in ordinal  and cardinal theory.

Comment: Read about Skolem's paradox.

Comment: @User1006 "I believe that cardinal is absolute, but there are somethings wrong in ordinal and cardinal theory." What do you mean, and on what basis exactly do you believe this?

Comment: From the answer above, how can $\omega_1$ collapse to a countable ordinal? My instinct is that cardinal is absolute, but something wrong in ordinals.

Comment: @User1006: No, the thing is that being a cardinal depends on what bijections you have in your model.

Comment: @User1006 Every model of ZF has an element it *thinks* is the first uncountable ordinal; but it may be wrong. There's no "something wrong in the ordinals" going on here - the issue is that the condition "is a model of ZF" is much weaker than you may think at first: it just guarantees that the axioms of ZF are satisfied *internally*, not that they are satisfied internally *in the "correct" way.* If you talk about a stronger condition - e.g. "is a model of **second-order** ZF" - then many things become absolute. But there is no "problem with the ordinals" going on here, it's a **logical** issue.

Comment: (Clarifying my second-to-last sentence above: if $M$ is a model of second-order ZF, then the thing $M$ thinks is $\omega_1$ is in fact the real $\omega_1$. That's what I mean by "becomes absolute.") Incidentally, it looks from these comments and your previous questions that a lot of your confusions will be cleared up if you understand the downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem and of the Mostowski collapse. The latter especially is relevant here, and the key is: if $M$ is a countable elementary submodel of the universe, and $N$ is its Mostowski collapse, the image of $\omega_1$ in $N$ is countable.

Comment: @User1006 It occurs to me looking back at this that your question "how can $\omega_1$ collapse to a countable ordinal" might be ultimately a confusion with the Mostowski collapse. The thing to keep in mind is that (i) a countable elementary submodel $M$ of the universe *will* contain $\omega_1$ as an *element*, since $\omega_1$ is definable, but (ii) such an $M$ will never contain $\omega_1$ as a *subset*, since $M$ itself is countable but $\omega_1$ is uncountable. What this means is that there is a huge "gap": $M$ contains some, but not all, of the countable ordinals (continued).

Comment: In particular, $M$ *will never be transitive*. There are countable *elementary* submodels, and there are countable *transitive* models, but never the twain shall meet. Now suppose $M$ is a countable elementary submodel and $m_M$ is the Mostowski collapse function on $M$. Then the point is: $m_M(\omega_1)\not=\omega_1$. I think if you understand this point, the rest will be much clearer. (As a warm-up, what's the Mostowski collapse of $\{\omega_1\}$?) The "something wrong" here isn't about ordinals or cardinals, it's about the limitations of first-order logic. (continued)

Comment: Specifically, it's about the [Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem). The existence of countable elementary submodels is exactly what makes cardinality non-absolute. This raises an interesting philosophical issue - how much set theory should be built into the underlying logic of mathematics? - which is outside the scope of this question, but one important point is: **absoluteness is relative to the logic used**. If you're interested in non-first-order logics, check out the quite nice book "Model-theoretic logics" (free on projecteuclid!).

Comment: @NoahSchweber, yes, Lowenheim-Skolem theorem causes all the problems. It used to be known as Skolem paradox, but nowadays people are complacent to believe it is no longer a paradox. But I do believe it is a paradox.

Comment: @User1006 It's really not (except in the sense of being a surprising fact) - it is a theorem about first-order logic. You might view it as an argument in favor of logics stronger than first-order logic, but that doesn't make it a paradox.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, I'd go a little further and say that cardinal properties are *seldom* absolute. Remember, "absolute" means that the property's truth value doesn't change when you move between larger and smaller models.

Even *being a cardinal* is not absolute. For example, it's fairly straightforward to construct a pair of models $M_0 \subseteq M_1$ so that the ordinal $M_0$ thinks is the first uncountable cardinal is actually countable in $M_1$ (so isn't a cardinal at all).

The issue is that most cardinal properties involve either the phrase "there exists..." or the phrase "for every...", once you navigate through all of the definitions. What that means is that, usually, you can either move *down* to a smaller model in which the thing that used to exist doesn't, or *up* to a larger model in which the thing that used to always be true has a counterexample.